# Find two elementary matrices $E_1$ and $E_2$ such that $E_2E_1A=B$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, and I need to find two matrices $E_1$ and $E_2$ that satisfy the question stated in the title.

\begin{align*}
A&=\begin{bmatrix}
           1&2&-1\\
           1&1&1\\
          1&-1&0\\
         \end{bmatrix} &
B&=\begin{bmatrix}
           1&-1&0\\
           1&1&1\\
          4&-1&-1
         \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
I know I need to find two elementary row operations that will turn $A$ into $B$, I think the first operation is switching the first and third row in $A$, but I don't know what the second operation would be.

Comment: You could compute $BA^{-1}$, and then try to recognize it as a product of two elementary matrices.

Comment: $(4.-1,-1)-(1,2,-1)=(3,-3,0)=3(1,-1,0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aim is to find $E_1$ and $E_2$ such that $B = E_2E_1A$. The first thing is to interchange the first and the last row of the matrix $A$, so $$E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad A_1 := E_1A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then, $B$ can be obtained by multiplying the first row of $A_1$ and adding it to the third row: $$E_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 &0\\3&0&1\end{bmatrix}, \quad B = E_2A_1.$$